# How can I continue in this situation?

Tags: analysis

[image]

I am stuck for a move as White. Is there any way to go for a check-mate? I would take the black rook with my rook at d1 but would that be a bad decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's too early to be thinking about forcing a checkmate. Instead, you should focus on centralizing your pieces and getting them to work together. Your Rook on h1 and Knight on b5 are out of play, and aren't constructively helping your Rook on d1 fight in the center (and attack against Black's King).

You could exchange on d8, but keep in mind that with less pieces on the board, it will be more difficult to attack the Black King. I think a better move would be to play Nc3. This gets your Knight out of danger, and on c3 the Knight does the following: 1) It protects your King, 2) It protects the a4-pawn, 3) It blocks the c-file so Black's Rooks can't invade on it, 4) The Knight on c3 can leap to the e4-square at any moment.

After moving your Knight to c3, I would suggest getting Rh1 into the game. At this point your 3 pieces will be working together, and you have good chances to mount an attack against the Black King (assuming that remains your goal).

Comment: Not so sure `Nc3` is a great move; it lets black hit the `f` and `h` pawns with the rook on `c5`. Can you supply some variations?

Comment: @Tony Ennis, True, but it's not like White has a lot of options. If 1. Nd4 then 1...Rcd5, and the Knight is lost due to the pin. If White exchanges on d8 that doesn't solve the problem with the f- and h-pawns (if anything it makes it worse because now White only has one Rook to defend them). Aftter 1. Nc3 Rf5 2. Rxd8 Kxd8 3. Re1 Kd7 4. Re3 Rh5 5. Ne4!? White has good play, and Black hasn't restored the material balance yet. It's important to note White should only take on d8 once getting the Knight back in the game with 1. Nc3, since he can then begin an immediate attack on the Black King.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a checkmate plan. Let's talk about it when you are able to queen a pawn. 1.Rxd8 is a reasonable move here.

Comment: What advantage does `Rxd8` confer?